# How to wrap a method inside a class using test.step from playwright

Tags: typescript, automation, allure, playwright-test

I ran into a problem for marking steps in an allure report. I have a class of auxiliary methods for the test and I want these classes to be signed in the report as I want it, but my function does not return the result

**This is my class**

```
class UserSteps {
    private integrationClient: APIRequestContext;
    private userIdsToDelete: string[] = [];

    constructor(integrationClient: APIRequestContext) {
        this.integrationClient = integrationClient;
    }

    async createUser(data: CreateUserRequest): Promise<CreateUserSuccessResponse> {
        await test.step(`Method Call /users with body: ${data}`, async () => {
            const response = await this.integrationClient.post('users', { data });
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            const user = responseJson.result;

            this.userIdsToDelete.push(user.id);

            return user;
        });
    }

    async tearDown(): Promise<void> {
        for (const userId of this.userIdsToDelete)
            try {
                await this.changeUserStatus(userId, { status: UserStatus.Deleted });
            } catch {
                console.log(`Error while deleting user: ${userId}`);
            }
    }
}
```

**This is my test**

```
    test('#162868', async ({ steps, web }) => {
        await web.page.goto(
            urlWithParams(AUTH_URL_AUTHORIZE, {
                client_id: clientId.test.name,
                redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
                response_type: ResponseType.Code,
                theme: Theme.Default,
            }),
        );
        const user = await steps.user.createUser(DEFAULT_USER_CLIENT);
        await web.steps.form.typePhone(user.phone);
    });
```

if I don't wrap using this part of the code in my class, everything works

```
await test.step(`Method Call /users with body: ${data}`, async () => {...})
```

but if I wrap I get an error.

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined

      40 |         );
      41 |         const user = await steps.user.createUser(DEFAULT_USER_CLIENT);
    > 42 |         await web.steps.form.typePhone(user.phone);
```

Please help =)

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like you’re just missing returning the user from createUser! All you should need to do is put `return` at the front of test.step, like this:

```js
return test.step(`Method Call /users with body: ${data}`, async () => {...})
```

Without that, createUser will just return `Promise<undefined>`, hence why the error complained about accessing phone on undefined. And when you removed the test.step wrapping, that actually left the `return user` statement, thus why the user is not undefined and it works.